# C++ function not working in different class

Tags: c++, matrix

I am really struggling with using functions and classes, and on VS, I get a "Matrix::Matrix()" is unaccessible error, and I just cannot figure out why.

I'm trying to learn about functions and classes and just am not getting it! The program basically uses a constructor and destructor in a class called `Matrix`, and creates a 'matrix'. I am now trying to use a function within this matrix class to get the value from inside of the constructed Matrix, and it will return the correct value, but don't understand why I am getting this error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
    Matrix();

private:
    int M;
    int N;
    double *data;


    int get(int i, int j){
        return data[i*N+j];
    }

    //CONSTRUCTOR
public:
    Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC,double * input_data)
    {
        M=sizeR;//Rows
        N=sizeC;//Columns

        data = new double[M*N];//creation of 1D array, uses m&n values

        cout<<"\nMatrix::Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double * input_data) is invoked\n\n";


        //ENTER DATA INTO MATRIX HERE:

        for(int i=0;i<M*N;i++)//Loops for every data entry into 1D array, uses r&c as referenece to size
            data[i] = input_data[i];//Accesses each value at specific location, inputs value 'val'

        for(int i=0;i<M*N;i++)//Loops for every data entry into 1D array
            cout<<data[i]<<" ";

    }


    //DECONSTRUCTOR
    ~Matrix(){
        //delete data
        delete []data;

        cout<<"\n\nMatrix::~Matrix() is invoked\n\n";
    }

};

int main()
{
    int sizeR, sizeC, g1, g2;

    g1 = 2;
    g2 = 2;

    Matrix M1;

    cout<<"Enter No. Rows: ";
    cin>>sizeR;

    cout<<"Enter No. Columns: ";
    cin>>sizeC;

    double * input_data;
    input_data = new double[sizeR*sizeC];


    //INPUTS VALUES TO ARRAY
    for(int i=0;i<sizeR*sizeC;i++)//Loops for every row
        input_data[i] = i+1*input_data[i-1];

    Matrix(sizeR, sizeC, input_data);

    cout<<"Find value at row: ";
    cin>>sizeR;
    cout<<"Find value at column: ";
    cin>>sizeC;

    M1.get(g1, g2);


}
```

Comment: As mentioned in some answers you are calling a private constructor, futher you have the line of code `Matrix(sizeR, sizeC, input_data);` which is also invalid -- are you trying to constrct two objects, or are you trying to provide parameters to the first object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create `M1` object using the constructor you provided.

The line `Matrix(sizeR, sizeC, input_data);` doesn't create `M1` object.

You need to do `Matrix M1(sizeR, sizeC, input_data);` or create the default constructor with public accessibility.

Furthermore (as somebody pointed out) `M1.get(...)` will also cause errors if `Matrix::get()` is not public.

Comment: Hi, I'd like to say thank you to all for the help and feedback!! Additionally I have tried numerous things and doing the Matrix M1(sizeR, sizeC, input_data); has allowed it to work, and even though you said to make the constructor having public accessibility should also work, it didn't. In all honesty not entirely sure why! If anyone would be able to explain why I'd appreciate it, as I am trying to ensure I understand what I am doing :)

Answer (score 4):

The default access modifier for classes in C++ is private so if you didn't explicitly used the `public:` access modifier before the definition of the constructor `Matrix()` then it would be considered to be private.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definition of the constructor which takes no parameters, and further its declaration is `private`. Therefore, the call

```
Matrix M1;
```

fails. Just provide a definition in your class such as

```
Matrix() {}
```

and make that public accessible and it will work fine.

---

**EDIT:** The `get` function as well need to be public. Next, this raw array is a bad thing which leeds to a double-free corruption error. Use a `std::vector` instead. This becomes code-review, I guess. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3cd9ec57a1c3312) for a still quick-n-dirty but somewhat improved implementation.

Comment: It will not "work fine" -- I don't think you looked at his code

Comment: You're right, I didn't. Just looked at the error message. There are more issues here.

Answer (score 1):

Just place your default constructor (declaration/definition) in your class' `public` section:

```
class Matrix {
public: // <<<<
    Matrix() {
    }
    Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC,double * input_data) { 
        // ...
    }
    // ...
};
```

The default scope policy for `class` is `private` unless specified differently.